# NodeJs can't return data from MongoDB to frontpage

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

This is my home.js router :

```
    var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var router = express.Router();


var Movie = require('../models/movie');
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false});


// Get Homepage
router.get('/', function(req, res){
    //get data from mongodb and pass it to view
    Movie.find({}, function(err, data){
        if (err) throw err;
        res.render('home', {movies: data});
        });
    });

function ensureAuthenticated(req, res, next){
    if(req.isAuthenticated()){
        return next();
    } else {
        //req.flash('error_msg','You are not logged in');
        res.redirect('/users/login');
    }

};
module.exports = router;
```

this is my models/movie

```
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

// Movie Schema
var MovieSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    movieName: {
        type: String,
        index:true
    },
    img: {
        type: String
    },
    description: {
        type: String
    },
});

var Movie = module.exports = mongoose.model('Movie', MovieSchema);
```

this is my homepage

```
    <h2 class="page-header">Резервирај Билет</h2>
<div class="movies-block">
  <div class="movie">
    <h3>Movie #1<h3>
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/c/c2/WALL-Eposter.jpg" width="150px" height="200px"></img></br>
    <button type="button" name="rezerviraj">Резервирај</button>
  </div>

  <div class="movie">
    <ul>
      <% for(var i=0; i<movies.length; i++){ %>
      <li><%= movies[i].item %></li>
      <% } %>
    </ul>
</div>
```

So, I can send data to db, but I can't retrieve it. I want to put out the data that is in my MongoDB to the front page. 
The goal is: I log in in the admin dashboard, add movie details (Movie name, pic and description). When I submit it, it goes to the MongoDB. From there, the front page requests the data and puts it where i want it. For now, i just get this code on the front page:

```
<% for(var i=0; i
<%= movies[i].item %>
<% } %>
```

Where am I making my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a comment, but I don't have enough rep to comment.

> For now, i just get this code on the front page
>       <% for(var i=0; i
>       <%= movies[i].item %>
>       <% } %>

You are using [EJS template engine](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ejs), are you sure you already set the `view engine` express app to `ejs`? It looks like not, since the template hasn't render the for expression.